# Compile coffeescript Ext.js Ext is not defined

Tags: extjs, coffeescript

I'd like to use coffeescript in an Ext.js project. What do I have to do in order to make the compiler to know the Ext namespace?
Whenever I compile an ext-js.coffee with node I get the error Ext is not defined

```
Ext is not defined
```

I'm sure it's a ridiculously easy to solve issue, but I'm stuck in a think-stack-overflow.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're executing it, not compiling it.

The compile syntax is

```
coffee -c filename.coffee
```

or if you want to watch it for change

```
coffee -wc filename.coffee
```

What you're - I think - running is

```
coffee filename.coffee
```

which is actually the same as

```
coffee -c filename.coffee && node filename.js
```